# Error Pulling image from ACR in Azure Function

Tags: docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-function-app, azure-container-registry, azure-web-app-for-containers

Please am trying to deploy an image in Azure Container Registry(ACR) on my Function App, but am not able to do it.
I pushed the latest image from pc to the ACR after creating it. Also the admin under access key is enable. Please advise how to resolve this. The log result can be found below.

```
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2020-11-02T15:05:03.452Z INFO  - Pulling image: myacrqa.azurecr.io/myimage:v1
2020-11-02T15:05:03.462Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://ifckpacrqa.azurecr.io/v2/: read tcp IP:17045->IP:443: read: connection reset by peer"}

2020-11-02T15:05:03.462Z ERROR - Pulling docker image myacrqa.azurecr.io/offlinekpqa:v1 failed:
2020-11-02T15:05:03.462Z INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: myacrqa.azurecr.io/offlinekpqa:v1
2020-11-02T15:05:03.470Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://ifckpacrqa.azurecr.io/v2/: read tcp IP:17047->IP:443: read: connection reset by peer"}

2020-11-02T15:05:03.471Z ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
2020-11-02T15:05:08.847Z INFO  - Stopping site ifc-kp-ml-qa because it failed during startup.
2020-11-02T15:10:01.023Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2020-11-02T15:10:01.024Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 8356:8081 --name ifc-kp-func_app_0_22558c6b_msiProxy -e WEBSITE_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=https://functions.azure.com,https://functions-staging.azure.com,https://functions-next.azure.com,https://storage.z13.web.core.windows.net -e WEBSITE_CORS_SUPPORT_CREDENTIALS=False -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=IFC-KP-ML-QA -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=True -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=xxxx -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=65631c3af46c684539e2d9f55e37247be307daaa00f59cdf3231284117e30b40 appsvc/msitokenservice:2007200210  

2020-11-02T15:10:01.025Z INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2020-11-02T15:10:04.362Z INFO  - Pulling image: ifckpacrqa.azurecr.io/offlinekpqa:v1
2020-11-02T15:10:04.372Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://myacrqa.azurecr.io/v2/: read tcp IP:17489->IP:443: read: connection reset by peer"}

2020-11-02T15:10:04.373Z ERROR - Pulling docker image myacrqa.azurecr.io/myimage:v1 failed:
2020-11-02T15:10:04.373Z INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: myacrqa.azurecr.io/myimage:v1
2020-11-02T15:10:04.398Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://ifckpacrqa.azurecr.io/v2/: read tcp 10.168.216.12:17491->52.168.114.2:443: read: connection reset by peer"}

2020-11-02T15:10:04.401Z ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
2020-11-02T15:10:09.853Z INFO  - Stopping site ifc-kp-ml-qa because it failed during startup.
2020-11-02T15:15:02.120Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2020-11-02T15:15:02.121Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 7603:8081 --name ifc-kp-ml-qa_0_969b061e_msiProxy -e WEBSITE_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=https://functions.azure.com,https://functions-staging.azure.com,https://functions-next.azure.com,https://storage.z13.web.core.windows.net -e WEBSITE_CORS_SUPPORT_CREDENTIALS=False -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=IFC-KP-ML-QA -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=True -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=ifc-kp-ml-qa.aseqa.ifc.org -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=65631c3af46c684539e2d9f55e37247be307daaa00f59cdf3231284117e30b40 appsvc/msitokenservice:2007200210  

2020-11-02T15:15:02.122Z INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2020-11-02T15:15:04.469Z INFO  - Pulling image: myacrqa.azurecr.io/myimage:v1
2020-11-02T15:15:04.479Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://myacrqa.azurecr.io/v2/: read tcp IP:17953->IP:443: read: connection reset by peer"}

2020-11-02T15:15:04.479Z ERROR - Pulling docker image myacrqa.azurecr.io/myimage:v1 failed:
2020-11-02T15:15:04.479Z INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: myacrqa.azurecr.io/myimage:v1
2020-11-02T15:15:04.487Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://myacrqa.azurecr.io/v2/: read tcp IP:17955->IP:443: read: connection reset by peer"}

2020-11-02T15:15:04.490Z ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
2020-11-02T15:15:09.926Z INFO  - Stopping site ifc-kp-ml-qa because it failed during startup.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pull the docker images from the ACR or other private registry, you need to set the environment variables like this:

[image]

You can set these environment variables in the Azure portal, function settings. Or use the Azure CLI command `az functionapp create` with the paramteres:

```
--deployment-container-image-name
--docker-registry-server-password
--docker-registry-server-user
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Charles Xu. But do I have to always set these manually? I thought its meant to pick those values automatically.

Comment: @Jaychuks For function, yes, you always need to set these manually.

Comment: I tried it. Still didn't work. The values were there already and even after changing the values in the configuration it didn't work.

Comment: @Jaychuks Can you share your environment variables with the values and the image in the ACR?

Comment: I was able to deploy the image on azure function after some firewall update. Quick question - 

I have a machine model that I deployed using docker on Azure Function(HTTP Trigger). Routinely, the directory of the machine learning model is expected to change and updated once a new file is uploaded to an Azure DataLake.

Please, How do I automate this process of updating the model on Azure Functions?

Comment: @Jaychuks I do not work on Machine Learning. So I have no ideas. I just help you with this issue. If it solves the issue, please accept it. And you can create another question for the ML.